# How do i Add effects to AudioStream in Unity

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I've been reading a lot of late but no lack, am trying to add effects like flanging, Child voice, Monster etc to unity Audio. 
I've studied studied the documentation but couldn't get any good example.
Am relatively new to Audio programming and C# please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a video tutorial about adding effects to the audio mixer in Unity:

http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/audio-effects

Hope this helps!